# How to Hide navigation bar from some pages in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.4, magento2.3.1

I have this requirement i,e i need to hide navigation bar for some pages. I need to develop these feature in such a way that in the future if we create a new page and if i need the same requirement for that page i can able to do it from admin.

i can think of custom layout handle but, i need to create layout xml file each time a new page is created with the above feature.

How can i achieve this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2, you can hide the navigation bar from specific pages by using a custom layout file for those pages. Here are the steps to do that:

1. Create a custom layout file for the page where you want to hide the navigation bar. For example, if you want to hide the navigation bar on the checkout page, create a file named checkout_index_index.xml in your custom module or theme.
2. In the custom layout file, add the following code to remove the navigation block:

`<referenceBlock name="catalog.topnav" remove="true" />`

This code will remove the "catalog.topnav" block, which contains the navigation menu, from the page.

3. Save the custom layout file and flush the Magento cache.

After following these steps, the navigation bar will be hidden on the page where you applied the custom layout file. Note that you can use the same approach to hide any other block or element from specific pages in Magento 2.

Happy Coding :)

Comment: HI Mayur Sisodiya, thanks for you response. But in the future if clients create a new pages and what if they want to hide nav bar for particualr pages?